# How can I match a Plotly graph theme to a Dash dashboard's background colour using Bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm struggling to get a solid/consistent background colour for my Dash app's background using Bootstrap.

Here's how I've got one of the graphs coded:

```
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
            x=[playerEAinfo['Crossing'].iloc[0], playerEAinfo['Finishing'].iloc[0],
                    playerEAinfo['LongPassing'].iloc[0],playerEAinfo['LongShots'].iloc[0],playerEAinfo['BallControl'].iloc[0],
                    playerEAinfo['Dribbling'].iloc[0], playerEAinfo['Positioning'].iloc[0],playerEAinfo['Vision'].iloc[0]],
            y=['Crossing', 'Finishing', 'Long Passes', 'Long Shots','Ball Control', 'Dribbling', 'Positioning','Vision'],text=[playerEAinfo['Crossing'].iloc[0], playerEAinfo['Finishing'].iloc[0],
                    playerEAinfo['LongPassing'].iloc[0],playerEAinfo['LongShots'].iloc[0],playerEAinfo['BallControl'].iloc[0],
                    playerEAinfo['Dribbling'].iloc[0], playerEAinfo['Positioning'].iloc[0],playerEAinfo['Vision'].iloc[0]],
                    textposition='auto',orientation='h',marker_color='green'))
        config = {'displayModeBar':False}
        fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark',margin=dict(l=10,r=10,b=10,t=10), width=260,height=280,
                        xaxis=dict(autorange=True,
                        showgrid=False,
                        ticks='',
                        showticklabels=False))
        fig.update_traces(opacity=.7)
```

And here's how the bootstrap section is coded:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CYBORG])
app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Card(
        dbc.CardBody([
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    drawPic(playerEAinfo)
                ], width=1.25, style={'height':'100%', 'border':'1px black solid', 'border-color':'grey','height':'281px'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawText(playerEAinfo)
                ], width=2.50,style={'height':'100%','border':'1px black solid', 'border-color':'grey','width':'197px', 'height':'281px'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawIndicator(playerEAinfo)
                ], width=2.25,style={'height':'100%','border':'1px black solid', 'border-color':'grey', 'width':'250px', 'height':'281px'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawBars(playerEAinfo, 1)
                ], width=3,style={'height':'100%','border':'1px black solid', 'border-color':'grey', 'height':'281px'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawBars(playerEAinfo, 2)
                ], width=3,style={'height':'100%', 'border':'1px black solid', 'border-color':'grey', 'height':'281px'})
            ],no_gutters=True), # Removes spacing between cards
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    drawRadar(fbref_playername)
                ], width=6, style={'height':'100%', 'border':'1px black solid', 'border-color':'grey'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawBars(playerEAinfo, 1)
                ], width=6, style={'height':'100%', 'border':'1px black solid', 'border-color': 'grey'})
            ],no_gutters=True),
            dbc.Row([
                dbc.Col([
                    drawBars(playerEAinfo, 1)
                ], width=6, style={'height': '100%', 'border': '1px black solid', 'border-color': 'grey'}),
                dbc.Col([
                    drawBars(playerEAinfo, 1)
                ], width=6, style={'height': '100%', 'border': '1px black solid', 'border-color': 'grey'})
            ], no_gutters=True),
        ])
    )
])
```

What it looks like currently:

[image: What it looks like currently]

What am I missing? Shouldn't the CYBORG theme kick in and colour all of the gray spots black?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use something like this to make the plot transparent:

````
fig.update_layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',paper_bgcolor='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)')```
````